# XSLT: Get value of xpath based on whether element exists

Tags: xml, xslt, xhtml

I would check if a document contains a value given and xpath and if it does use the selected value otherwise use another. I'm really bad at XSLT but here is what I'm starting with:

```
  <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test="p//section.std[@type = 'SpecialSection']/p/img/@alt">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="p//section.std[@type = 'SpecialSection']/p/img/@alt"/>
          </xsl:when>
          <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="p//meta-data.titles/meta-data.title"/>
          </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
```

Currently no value is selected. I suspect that I cannot write my choose test like I have. I'm not sure if an empty value evaluates to a boolean or not. Basically I would like to test if the first xpath returns a value and if it does use it and if not use the one in the  block.

Any help?

Comment: You are doing the test correctly - The XPath returns a node set, and a node set is evaluated to true iff it is not empty. I suppose the error is in the method you use to output your values... have you tried to use <xsl:value-of> instead of <xsl:apply-templates>?

Comment: In particular, an `img` that has an `alt=""` will be matched, even though the attribute value is empty.  If you want to exclude such matches you need to do something like `..../p/img/@alt[string()]` (which only matches alt attributes with a non-empty string value).

Comment: We can't tell if this snippet of code is correct without seeing the input. Please supply a simplified sample input document and expected output. Also which version of XSLT are you using? 1.0? or 2.0?

Comment: Also, I noticed that you tagged the question [tag:xhtml]. If your input document is xhtml, your p elements will need the xhtml prefix. Your current snipped of code will not match any xhtml:p elements.

Comment: Nick, People are trying to *guess*. Please, give us (edit the question and enter there) a small example of the source XHTML document and of a complete transformation. Also, please, provide the exact wanted result from the transformation.

Answer (score 1):

**You can select the wanted node just with the following single expression** (the `select` attribute of the `xsl:variable` below):

```
<xsl:variable select=
 "p//section.std[@type = 'SpecialSection']/p/img/@alt
 |
  p[not(.//section.std[@type = 'SpecialSection']/p/img/@alt)]
                                           //meta-data.titles/meta-data.title
 "/>
```

Comment: your second predicate needs to include `p/img/@alt` .